# resolving IllegalArgumentException with database connection

Tags: java, for-loop, jtable, database-connection, illegalargumentexception

please help. I have this program that connects to a database. it connects perfectly, but this block of code when executed contains an IllegalArgumentException. This method should retrieve data from my database then put it in a jtable. at first, it works fine (putting the retrieved data from the database in the jtable) but when i added the "for-loop" for iterating the data in each cell in the jtable, which also executes the adding of checked checkboxes, this kind of error occurs. what should i do to resolve this? thanks in advanced.

```
private void loadAttendance(){
    int counter = 0;
    try {
        String query = "SELECT ID,firstName,lastName,position,rate,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 FROM employees";            
        Object[][] result = connectToDB(query);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        int val = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        System.out.println(val);
        String [] dates;

        if(val >= 1 && val <=15){
            attendanceTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            result, dates = new String [] {"ID","First Name", "Last Name", "Position","Daily Rate","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15", "Total", "Gross Pay", "Vale","Net Pay"}
        ) 
        {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Double.class,java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Double.class, java.lang.Double.class, java.lang.Double.class, java.lang.Double.class
            };

            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
                false, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, false, true, false
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        });
            for (int i = 0 ; i < attendanceTable.getRowCount(); i++){
                for (int j = 4 ; j <= 14; j++){
                    result[i][j] = attendanceTable.getValueAt(i,j);
                    System.out.println(" " + i + " " + j + " " + result[i][j]);
                    if(result[i][j] != null && result[i][j].equals(true)){
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
               System.out.println(counter);
               attendanceTable.setValueAt(counter,i,19);
               counter = 0;

               int a = (Integer) attendanceTable.getValueAt(i,19);
               System.out.println(a+"  -value for days");

               double d = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(attendanceTable.getValueAt(i,5)));
               System.out.println(d+"   -value for daily rate");

               double product = a*d;
               attendanceTable.setValueAt(product,i,20);
               System.out.println("sample"+product);
            }
        }else{
            attendanceTable.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            result, dates = new String [] {"ID","First Name", "Last Name", "Position", "16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31", "Total", "Daily Rate","Gross Pay", "Vale","Net Pay"}
        ) 
        {
            Class[] types = new Class [] {
                java.lang.Integer.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.String.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Boolean.class, java.lang.Double.class, java.lang.Double.class, java.lang.Double.class, java.lang.Double.class, java.lang.Double.class
            };
            boolean[] canEdit = new boolean [] {
               false, true, true, false, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, true, false, true, false, true, false
            };

            public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                return types [columnIndex];
            }

            public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
                return canEdit [columnIndex];
            }
        }); 
            for (int i = 0 ; i < attendanceTable.getRowCount(); i++){
                for (int j = 0 ; j <= attendanceTable.getColumnCount(); j++){
                    result[i][j] = attendanceTable.getValueAt(i,j);
                    System.out.println(" " + i + " " + j + " " + result[i][j]);
                    if(result[i][j] != null && result[i][j].equals(true)){
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
               System.out.println(counter);
               attendanceTable.setValueAt(counter,i,19);
               counter = 0;

               Integer a = (Integer) attendanceTable.getValueAt(i,19);
               System.out.println(a+"  -value for days");

               Double d =(Double) attendanceTable.getValueAt(i,20);
               System.out.println(d+"   -value for daily rate");

               Double product = a*d;
               attendanceTable.setValueAt(product,i,21);
            }
        }
        for(int x = 0; x <= dates.length-1; x++){
            System.out.println(dates[x]);
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(MainFrame.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you tell us the line no where you are getting exception?

Comment: Post the stack trace, which should indicate exactly which line of your code is throwing the exception. Then identify which line of your code is the offending line. Isolating the problem for potential helpers will get you an answer much faster than posting a blob of code which may or may not contain the problem.